# how to set permission using @can @endcan in config.ui using php laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, config, smartadmin

i'm overhandle a system using laravel and SmartAdmin UI as the admin panel. i have implemented roles  and permission in my system.

if i'm using usual blade like index.blade.php, i can configured the permission using @can, like below

```html
@can('view_document')
      //////
@endcan
```

but since i use admin panel and the menu using config.ui, i don't know how to implementend @can @endcan in my code

```html
<?php
//CONFIGURATION for SmartAdmin UI
//ribbon breadcrumbs config
//array("Display Name" => "URL");
$breadcrumbs = array(
    "Home" => APP_URL
);
/*navigation array config
ex:
"dashboard" => array(
    "title" => "Display Title",
    "url" => "http://yoururl.com",
    "url_target" => "_blank",
    "icon" => "fa-home",
    "label_htm" => "<span>Add your custom label/badge html here</span>",
    "sub" => array() //contains array of sub items with the same format as the parent
)
*/
$page_nav = array(
    "dashboard" => array(
        "title" => "Dashboard",
        "url" => "ajax/dashboard.php",
        "icon" => "fa-home"
    ),
    
);
//configuration variables
$page_title = "";
$page_css = array();
$no_main_header = false; //set true for lock.php and login.php
$page_body_prop = array(); //optional properties for <body>
$page_html_prop = array(); //optional properties for <html>
?>
```

what i want is, i can use @can @endcan function on the menu, so user can only access the menu based on their role and permission.

i try add @can before   "dashboard" => array(
but give me an error

Answer (score 1):

If you are using any 3rd party packages for permissions as spatie/laravel-permissions than you can just use their permission to do that, if you are using Laravel Gates I would suggest you to read this part of docs.
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization